# Error "insert into"

Tags: sql, sql-insert

i'm building a small project with c#. And i getting a problem with the insert into database. I tried to understand what is the problem with this command and i can't figure it out. 
There is a link to the project: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2QZzcPyN4G0VTRRNWowLVg5V1U/view?usp=docslist_api

I know it's in hebrew.. but what is matter is the code line.
I hope you will give me a solution as fast as posible. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Nobody's going to follow this link. Please paste the problematic code and the error it produces here.

Comment: And tell us which DBMS you are using

Comment: This is the problematic code:

string strSql = "INSERT INTO Stock(FoundCode,Description,Catagory,WhereFound,StoreAt,DateFound,FounderName,Section,Returned,BoxNumber,KabatName) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + comboBox4.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox3.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt16(checkBox1.Checked) + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "')";